# AES decrypt in Ruby and Scala (or Java)

Tags: java, ruby, scala, encryption, aes

I'm encoding using AES-CBC-128 in Ruby and I'm trying to decode it in Java but I can't get it to work.

Here is the code I use to decrypt in Ruby :

```
require 'openssl'

iv = "\x30\xd2\xff\x5d\x08\xac\x83\x95\x02\x0f\x23\x20\x81\xc9\xc1\xe4"
key = "1234567890ABCDEF1234567890ABCDEF"
message = "\xb8\x9f\x27\x30\xe5\x4d\x81\xf3\xa9\x3d\x0b\xe3\xaa\x52\x50\x15"


openssl_cipher = OpenSSL::Cipher.new('aes-128-cbc')
openssl_cipher.decrypt
openssl_cipher.key = key
openssl_cipher.iv = iv
result = openssl_cipher.update(message)
result << openssl_cipher.final

puts result
```

If you run this snippet it will output the string `matt`
Now I'm trying to achieve the same thing in Scala, using the implementation of the Java API. Here is my non-working code :

```
import javax.crypto.Cipher
import javax.crypto.spec.{SecretKeySpec, IvParameterSpec}

object Main {
    def main(argv: Array[String]) {
        val iv = Array(0x30,0xd2,0xff,0x5d,0x08,0xac,0x83,0x95,0x02,0x0f,0x23,0x20,0x81,0xc9,0xc1,0xe4).map { _.toByte }
        val keyBytes = "1234567890ABCDEF1234567890ABCDEF".getBytes("UTF-8")
        //val keyBytes = Array(0x12, 0x34, 0x56, 0x78, 0x90, 0xAB, 0xCD, 0xEF, 0x12, 0x34, 0x56, 0x78, 0x90, 0xAB, 0xCD, 0xEF).map { _.toByte }
        val message = Array(0xb8,0x9f,0x27,0x30,0xe5,0x4d,0x81,0xf3,0xa9,0x3d,0x0b,0xe3,0xaa,0x52,0x50,0x15).map { _.toByte }
        val key = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "AES")
        val cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/NoPadding")
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, new IvParameterSpec(iv))
        val result = cipher.doFinal(message)

        println(new String(result, "UTF-8"))
    }
}
```

I've tried both keyBytes, but none is working. I don't see what I'm missing to make it work.

Comment: Please, everytime somebody posts "none is working" as error description, one of my braincells commits suicide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only want 16 bytes of your key, so the line

```
val key = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "AES")
```

should be

```
val key = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes.take(16), "AES")
```

Comment: I guess we need a stackoverflow variant of `git merge` :)

Comment: Your Ruby code is asking for 'aes-128-cbc' -- 128-bit key, which is 16-bytes. Try 'aes-256-cbc' for a 256-bit (32-byte) key, and it might work with the full keyBytes. The only difference is the key size.

Answer (score 0):

Try `"AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding"` instead of `"AES/CBC/NoPadding"`. OpenSSL defaults to PKCS#7 padding, which is implemented by `"PKCS5Padding"` in Java. Note that PKCS#5 padding and PKCS#7 padding [are more or less equivalent](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/9043/1172).